# are all the planet in the same plane?

Tags: orbit, solar-system, planet

are all the planet in solar system the same plane in the space or not ? if yes is there any especial reason ? and if no how do they orbits then ?
as far as i know they are in the same plane , but is that mean they are exactly in same plane or its some thing near that ?
I would also like to know if they all orbit in the same direction ?
Is any of the picture below describing them true ?!

[image]

[image]

Comment: how about the direction of orbit , are they all in the same direction ?